# How do i use multiple files to access them in viewController?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

i am trying to programically create a Stackview that contains a TextField saying "Hello world"

```
class stackview: UIViewController {

    func setupview() {

        // Define TextField
        let Textfield = UITextView()
        Textfield.allowsEditingTextAttributes = false
        Textfield.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        Textfield.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70).isActive = true
        Textfield.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70).isActive = true
        Textfield.isEditable = false

        // Define the stackview, and setting up the attributes
        let stackview = UIStackView()
        stackview.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.horizontal
        stackview.distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.equalCentering
        stackview.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.center
        stackview.spacing = 5
        stackview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(stackview)
        stackview.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        stackview.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        Textfield.text = "hello"

        view.addSubview(Textfield)

    }
```

in my Viewcontroller.swift i want to access this function in ViewDidLoad

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var level = stackview()
        level.setupview()
    }
```

but the Hello world dosnt seem to appear!

Comment: After line  level.setupview() you need to added view to your parent view ... self.view.addSubView(level.view) try this

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this.

**stackview.swift**

```
import UIKit

class stackview: UIViewController {

    func setupview(myView: UIView) {

        // Define TextField
        let Textfield = UITextView()
        Textfield.allowsEditingTextAttributes = false
        Textfield.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        Textfield.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70).isActive = true
        Textfield.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70).isActive = true
        Textfield.isEditable = false

        // Define the stackview, and setting up the attributes
        let stackview = UIStackView()
        stackview.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.horizontal
        stackview.distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.equalCentering
        stackview.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.center
        stackview.spacing = 5
        stackview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(stackview)
        stackview.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        stackview.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        Textfield.text = "hello"

        myView.addSubview(Textfield)
    }
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let level = stackview()
        level.setupview(myView: self.view)
    }
}
```

Comment: why do i have to create a myView parameter. i am simply refering to view inside my function?

Comment: to pass current view to stackview @user3211359

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up View Controllers with Views, subViews and StackViews...

Look at this approach:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // define a UITextView and its properties
    var theTextView: UITextView = {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.allowsEditingTextAttributes = false
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70).isActive = true
        textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70).isActive = true
        textView.isEditable = false
        return textView
    }()

    // define a UIStackView and its properties
    var theStackView: UIStackView = {
        let stackview = UIStackView()
        stackview.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.horizontal
        stackview.distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.equalCentering
        stackview.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.center
        stackview.spacing = 5
        stackview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return stackview
    }()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // add the Stack View to this view - must be done before adding relative constraints
        self.view.addSubview(theStackView)

        // add relative constraints to the Stack View
        theStackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        theStackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        // set the text of the Text View
        theTextView.text = "hello"

        // add the Text View as an Arranged Subview of the Stack View
        theStackView.addArrangedSubview(theTextView)
    }

}
```

Now, later in your code, you can reference the Stack View with the `theStackView` variable / property - for adding additional arranged subviews, for example:

```
theStackView.addArrangedSubview(anotherTextView)
theStackView.addArrangedSubview(anImageView)
theStackView.addArrangedSubview(aButton)
```

and you can access the Text View with the `theTextView` variable / property - for changing the text, for example.